# OWASP AppSensor: Sending events is not triggering responses

Tags: spring-boot, owasp

I am running AppSensor as per instructions at https://github.com/jtmelton/appsensor/blob/master/sample-apps/DemoSetup.md.

Everything looks beautiful when I run client data generator.

I am adding events at http://localhost:8085/api/v1.0/events from my desktop app and they appear on dashboard and also on map just fine. But they are not triggering responses.

The requests that I am sending from my app are identical to ones generated by  client data generator. Few examples are below:

```
{"user":{"username":"bob","ipAddress":{"address":"10.10.10.1","geoLocation":{"latitude":37.596758,"longitude":-121.647992}}},"detectionPoint":{"category":"Input Validation","label":"IE1","responses":[]},"timestamp":"2017-05-08T17:07:06.076Z","detectionSystem":{"detectionSystemId":"myclientapp"},"metadata":[]}

{"user":{"username":"bob","ipAddress":{"address":"10.10.10.1","geoLocation":{"latitude":37.596758,"longitude":-121.647992}}},"detectionPoint":{"category":"Input Validation","label":"IE2","responses":[]},"timestamp":"2017-05-08T17:07:06.076Z","detectionSystem":{"detectionSystemId":"myclientapp"},"metadata":[]}

{"user":{"username":"bob","ipAddress":{"address":"10.10.10.1","geoLocation":{"latitude":37.596758,"longitude":-121.647992}}},"detectionPoint":{"category":"Request","label":"RE3","responses":[]},"timestamp":"2017-05-08T15:56:47.473Z","detectionSystem":{"detectionSystemId":"myclientapp"},"metadata":[]}}

{"user":{"username":"bob","ipAddress":{"address":"10.10.10.1","geoLocation":{"latitude":37.596758,"longitude":-121.647992}}},"detectionPoint":{"category":"Authentication","label":"AE4","responses":[]},"timestamp":"2017-05-08T17:07:06.076Z","detectionSystem":{"detectionSystemId":"myclientapp"},"metadata":[]}
```

I can't figure out why my requests do not trigger responses from server where identical requests from data generator tool does.

UPDATE 1:
I was asked if I am sending enough events to trigger a response and answer is yes.

UPDATE 2:
I was asked to share server log and [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/r1a8d59bvn5kuwl/server.log?dl=0) it is.

UPDATE 3:
I was asked to try using cURL and I did. Same results. That is events are recorded but no response is triggered. I sent curl request (identical timestamp) below about 50 times.

```
curl -v --header "Content-Type: application/json" --header "X-Appsensor-Client-Application-Name2: myclientapp" -X POST -d '{"user":{"username":"bob","ipAddress":{"address":"10.10.10.1","geoLocation":{"latitude":37.596758,"longitude":-121.647992}}},"detectionPoint":{"category":"Input Validation","label":"IE1","responses":[]},"timestamp":"2017-05-08T15:56:47.473Z","detectionSystem":{"detectionSystemId":"myclientapp"},"metadata":[]}' http://localhost:8085/api/v1.0/events
```

Same request formatted for windows

```
curl -v --header "Content-Type: application/json" --header "X-Appsensor-Client-Application-Name2: myclientapp" -X POST -d "{\"user\":{\"username\":\"bob\",\"ipAddress\":{\"address\":\"10.10.10.1\",\"geoLocation\":{\"latitude\":37.596758,\"longitude\":-121.647992}}},\"detectionPoint\":{\"category\":\"Input Validation\",\"label\":\"IE1\",\"responses\":[]},\"timestamp\":\"2017-05-08T15:56:47.473Z\",\"detectionSystem\":{\"detectionSystemId\":\"myclientapp\"},\"metadata\":[]}" http://localhost:8085/api/v1.0/events
```

UPDATE 4: Thanks to @jtmelton for his help. By looking at code I realized that my appsensor server and my client app were using different timezone. As soon as I added timezone to my timestamps it worked!!!

Comment: Are you sending enough events to trigger a given response? According to the config (https://github.com/jtmelton/appsensor/blob/master/sample-apps/appsensor-ws-rest-server-with-websocket-boot/src/main/resources/appsensor-server-config.xml), I would probably try to send 6 or more events in 30 seconds to trigger logging. If you send 12 it should trigger logout, and 18 should trigger disableUser. How many are you sending?

Comment: Yes, I am. I tried sending events up to 50-60 in under 20 seconds. Does the events have to be from a single session in order to generate responses? I see in SimpleDataGenerator.java every event type has its own thread that creates events in a loop. Where my C# code creates new instances of HttpClientHandler and HttpClient for every request.

Comment: Okay, I tried sending events from single instance of HttpClientHandler and HttpClient and still no responses from server.

Comment: If you're sending that many, it should be creating the results. Can you post (either here or via email) the log that is associated with the server while you're sending these requests?

Comment: [Server log](https://www.dropbox.com/s/r1a8d59bvn5kuwl/server.log?dl=0)

Comment: When I added 50+ events shown in attachment above. I saw activity on geo map and dashboard but did not see any responses. I queried http://localhost:8085/api/v1.0/reports/responses and got empty array.

Comment: Honestly, all of that looks correct. I've never seen this particular failure before. Mind filing a ticket with this info attached, and possibly the tool you're using as a replacement client? Another (quick) testing option would be to run this with curl and make sure it's not your httpclient itself (I assume not, but curl sometimes finds weird bugs).

Comment: Ok, Shahid, I hope I've found the issue. Given that this is intended to be a "real-time" system, I think that the issue is that while you're sending the events quickly enough to trigger the issue, there's an additional requirement that the event timestamp(s) must occur within the appropriate window _relative to the current time_. So, I would try again with the same input data, just bump the time up to a few minutes ahead of current time to be safe, or, you could script it and make the time based on the current clock. When I did this, it worked well for me. (code ref in next comment)

Comment: See https://github.com/jtmelton/appsensor/blob/76358d154c574bcae386ff88355adc55853e1d25/analysis-engines/appsensor-analysis-reference/src/main/java/org/owasp/appsensor/analysis/ReferenceEventAnalysisEngine.java#L132 for reference.

Comment: My app sends current timestamp with each request. By looking at the countEvents method it occurred to me that I am not sending in timezone information. As soon as I added timezone it worked. Thank you @jtmelton for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to update 4 on the question. Always include timezone in your timestamp. In my case request timestamps were earlier than server time so they were ignored.

C#

> DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss.fffzzz")

Answer (score 0):

In my understanding the appsensor demo won't give you any meaningful REST response on your request.

The *REST / WebSocket server* from the demo depends on `appsensor-ws-rest-server-2.2.0.jar` which provides endpoints in class [RestRequestHandler](https://github.com/jtmelton/appsensor/blob/master/execution-modes/appsensor-ws-rest-server/src/main/java/org/owasp/appsensor/handler/RestRequestHandler.java). Any POST to `/api/v1.0/events` or `/api/v1.0/attacks` is answered with `HTTP 201 - created` by method `public void addEvent(Event event)`. For some reason in my CURL tests I observed a `HTTP 204 - no content`, but never mind.

Responses can be read from the `/api/v1.0/responses` endpoint, e.g. using [EventManager](https://github.com/jtmelton/appsensor/blob/6bed31712daf68cb9d43bbf6a201098c9c62ef6c/appsensor-core/src/main/java/org/owasp/appsensor/core/event/EventManager.java)'s method `public Collection<Response> getResponses(String earliest)` where `earliest` is a DateTime value. Since `earliest` is the only query parameter, you'll receive responses for all users stored by the server since the given dateTime. With the *REST / WebSocket server* from the demo I don't see any possibility to get notified by appsensor, you have to query explicitly for responses from your application.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but thats not it. When you have enough number of events of certain type you expect server to recognize an attack and trigger a response to it. While using REST one would need to query attacks and responses endpoints to get server's recommendations. My problem is that no matter how many events I send, server does not see them as attack and does not trigger response. I noticed getting HTTP 204 - No content as well.